# How to find FeedItem where a ContentDocument is the RelatedRecordId

Tags: soql, contentdocument, feeditem

Given a ContentDocument, I need a way to use SOQL to find any FeedItems that the ContentDocument may be related to.

I hoped that ContentDocumentLink would work, but that just seems to give me the case and the user, but not the actual post in the feed.

I tried to do a simple query on FeedItem to see if I can just get it from RelatedRecordId

```
Select Id FROM FeedItem Where RelatedRecordId = '123AAA'
```

but then I get the error field "'RelatedRecordId' can not be filtered in a query call"

I cannot think of any other way to get to the FeedItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider querying `FeedAttachment`, which represents an attachment to a `FeedItem`.

Knowing that you already have the `ContentDocumentId`, you can build the query as follows :

```
SELECT Id, RecordId, FeedEntityId 
from FeedAttachment 
where RecordId IN ( select Id from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId ='069XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

`FeedEntityId` is the FeedItem Id and `RecordId` is the ContentVersion Id

**Note**: Seems that there is some limitation in accessing `FeedEntity.FieldName` in same query so you can build a set of FeedEntityIds and run another SOQL to retrieve more details on `FeedItem` if needed.

Refer to [FeedAttachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm) documentation for more details

Comment: Thanks, too bad about not being able to get the FeedEntitiy fields, but I think this will work for what I need.